# Cannot start container "catalina,sh": executable file not found in $PATH

Tags: docker

I am trying to start a container from an image built with the `Dockerfile` below.

```
FROM tomcat:8.0-jre8
MAINTAINER myname
ENV myenv 8.0
ADD jenkins.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/jenkins.war
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["catalina,sh", "run"]
```

However, I am getting the following error:

> Error response from daemon: Cannot start container [8] System error:
>   exec: "catalina,sh": executable file not found in $PATH

Answer (score 2):

Your command has a `,` instead of a `.`.
It should be `catalina.sh`